# Laravel 5.4 Form Request unique validation: how to access id?

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-5, request, unique

I have this form request as follows:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Sociallink;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

class SociallinkRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
          'seq' => 'required|unique:sociallinks,seq,' . $this->id . ',id',
          'social_name' => 'required|unique:sociallinks,social_name,' . $this->id . ',id',
          'cssclass' => 'required',
          'url' => 'nullable|active_url'
        ];
    }
```

I need the fields `seq` and `social_name` as unique. When I am trying to edit, this code is not working. I found that `$this->id` doesnt exist from `dd($this)`. My URL is: `http://prj.test/sociallink/2/edit`. Many examples here make use of `$this->id` but I cant access the variable anywhere in my code as it seems to be non existent. When I replace `$this->id` with a physical `id` like `2` in this example then the validation works fine. But dynamically, how do I use the current row's `id` to do the unique validation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unless you have a form input with the `id`, it is not actually in the `$request` (`$this` in your Request code).  You can verify this by returning the whole request from your controller:

```php
return request()->all();
```

Assuming you have this route defined something like:

```php
sociallink/{sociallink}/edit ...
```

Then in your Request you can do:

```php
public function rules()
{
    $sociallink = $this->route('sociallink');
    return [
      'seq'         => 'required|unique:sociallinks,seq,' . $sociallink . ',id',
      'social_name' => 'required|unique:sociallinks,social_name,' . $sociallink . ',id',
      'cssclass'    => 'required',
      'url'         => 'nullable|active_url'
    ];
}
```

There is an example of this in the [Form Request documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#form-request-validation):

> Also note the call to the `route` method in the example above. This method grants you access to the URI parameters defined on the route being called, such as the `{comment}` parameter in the example below:
>
> `Route::post('comment/{comment}');`

Comment: Awesome answer! You just made my valentine's day! Just a note however, `$this->route()` itself points to the current route and the parameter, `sociallink` in this case, is the name of the route parameter and not the name of the route. Hence, `$this->route('sociallink')` returns the parameter passed to the route and therefore, in the code that follows later, `$sociallink->id` is not required but instead the name of the variable that the value was assigned to, which in this case is '$sociallink` is enough. The validation code hence: `'required|unique:sociallinks,seq,' . $sociallink . ',id'`.

Comment: @somnath And you just made my day with your comment :-) You're quite right about the model, my mistake, I've updated my answer.